# Purpose of verify method in setDefaultHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can you please tell me what the below code does? Where is the hostname fetched from and what is the purpose of verify method?

```
static {
    //for localhost testing only
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

                public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                      javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    System.out.println(" hostname = " + hostname);
                    if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: The class is named `HostnameVerifier`, so what do you think the `verify` method would verify? *The host name*. --- Where did it get it from? *The parameter*. --- Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`HostnameVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html)? --- What does that actual method do? It allows HTTPS connections to `localhost` and rejects all others.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. In my case the the url that I am making a call to is same as the hostname that I am printing in the method. The url has has a context path in addition to the hostname - https://hostname/config/dev. The hostname that gets printed from the sys out statement is just the hostname value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to a HTTPS URL, the target site presents its certificate which contains a list of domains for which the certificate can be used. (see example image below). This is verified by Java when you obtain a `HttpsURLConnection`

In the code that you posted, you are defining a `HostnameVerifier` which gets invoked when the above check fails. And if the domain you are connecting to is localhost, you are allowing the connection setup to continue. This allows you to use any certificate for services at https://localhost domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ranjith. Does the url that I connect to return the certificate information? When I comment the it condition , I see an error message saying the dns expected is “local host” though the certificate doesn’t have that as DNS.

Comment: As part of establishing the HTTPS connection, the server that you are connecting to sends the certificate. You can open the URL in chrome and view the 'Subject Alternative Names' (SAN) as highlighted in the image above. https://medium.com/rapidsslonline/quick-steps-to-view-ssl-certificate-in-google-chrome-60a02f0e92f5. If localhost is not in the SAN list, you'll get the error that you are describing. The code that you posted in your question prevents that error.

Comment: I wonder if there is any scenario where returning `true` for `localhost` would become a vulnerability?